# "Cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags" after moving packages?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I only moved around some domain packages and started getting this error. If I move the packages back in the previous order, without changing any relationships or fetch types, the error is gone. How is this error related to the way domain modules are organized?